# AngularJS error: Provider must return value from $get factory method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication

What I'm trying to build is a login service.
I have written a factory that I need to be used by every controller. It's for checking whether user is logged in or not. But I'm getting this error:

```
Provider must return value from $get factory method
```

I'm very much new to Angular. Here is my index page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Index Page</title>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/lib/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/lib/angular-route.js"></script>

        <script src="app/app.js"></script>
        <script src="app/AuthenticationService.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js file:

```
( function () {

    angular.module('myApp', [
        'ngRoute',
        'ngAnimate',
        'myApp.login',
        'myApp.home',
        'myApp.AuthenticationService'
    ])  
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/login', {
            controller: 'LoginController',
            templateUrl: 'loginView.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .when('/home', {
            controller: 'HomeController',
            templateUrl: 'HomeView.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/login'
        });
    }]);    
})();
```

And this is the factory that I set up:

```
    (function() {

    angular
    .module('myApp.AuthenticationService', [])

    .factory('AuthService', ["$http", "$location", function($http, $location){
        var vm = this;
        vm.checkToken = function(token){
            var data = {token: token};
            $http.post("endpoints/checkToken.php", data).success(function(response){
                if (response === "unauthorized"){
                    console.log("Logged out");
                    $location.path('/login');
                } else {
                    console.log("Logged In");
                    return response;
                }
            }).error(function(error){
                $location.path('/login');
            })

        }

    }]);

    })();

And this is how I inject it in a controller:

(function() {

    angular
        .module('myApp.home', [])

        .controller('HomeController', function($routeParams,AuthService) {
                var vm = this;      

                //If user is not logged in
                var token;
                if (localStorage['token']){
                token = JSON.parse(localStorage['token']);
                } else {
                token = "something stupid";
                }
                AuthService.checkToken(token);

                $scope.logout = function(){
                    var data = {
                        token: token
                    }

                    $http.post('endpoints/logout.php', data).success(function(response){
                        console.log(response)
                        localStorage.clear();
                        $state.go("login");
                    }).error(function(error){
                        console.error(error);
                    })
                }

        });

})();
```

Can anyone point out the mistake I made? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Missing return statement for the factory:

Answer (score 4):

```
 .factory('AuthService', ["$http", "$location", function($http, $location){
        var vm = this;
        vm.checkToken = function(token){
            var data = {token: token};
            $http.post("endpoints/checkToken.php", data).success(function(response){
                if (response === "unauthorized"){
                    console.log("Logged out");
                    $location.path('/login');
                } else {
                    console.log("Logged In");
                    return response;
                }
            }).error(function(error){
                $location.path('/login');
            })

        }
       return vm;
    }]);
```

Angular factory should return an object to be consumed by the controller.

Comment: `vm` (View Model) is used in a controller and not in a Service. Also, I think is better to use an `{}` (new object) instead of `this`, because the factory it is not gonna be instantiated and the `this` has the reference of something else that is not the expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {

angular
.module('myApp.AuthenticationService', [])

.factory('AuthService', ["$http", "$location", function($http, $location){
    var vm = {};
    vm.checkToken = function(token){
        var data = {token: token};
        $http.post("endpoints/checkToken.php", data).success(function(response){
            if (response === "unauthorized"){
                console.log("Logged out");
                $location.path('/login');
            } else {
                console.log("Logged In");
                return response;
            }
        }).error(function(error){
            $location.path('/login');
        })

    }

    return vm;
}]);

})();
```

or below is the better way to create factory:

```
(function() {

angular
.module('myApp.AuthenticationService', [])

.factory('AuthService', ["$http", "$location", function($http, $location){

    var vm = {
        checkToken: checkToken
    };

    function checkToken(token){
        var data = {token: token};
        $http.post("endpoints/checkToken.php", data).success(function(response){
            if (response === "unauthorized"){
                console.log("Logged out");
                $location.path('/login');
            } else {
                console.log("Logged In");
                return response;
            }
        }).error(function(error){
            $location.path('/login');
        })

    }

    return vm;
}]);

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is because you are not returning an object in the factory function. In your case, instead of using `.factory()`, you need to use `.service()`. This is because your are using a constructor function (using `this` inside the function). If you want to use factory you can do as follow:

```
.factory('AuthService', ["$http", "$location", function($http, $location){
    var service = {
       checkToken: function() {...}
    };

    return service;
}])
```

You can follow the [John Papa Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#singletons) and prefer use factory instead of service.